# set android:layout_rowspan and android:layout_columnspan programmatically

Tags: android, grid-layout

I have different sized views that I'm arranging dynamically in a grid layout. I need to span the views pragmatically.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="2"
                tools:context=".GridXMLActivity" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                    android:text="Layout 1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:text="Layout 3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:text="Layout 3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:text="Layout 2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:text="Layout 2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:text="Layout 2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:text="Layout 3" />
            </GridLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have three different sized view inside my grid layout. 
Now i don't want to hard code these views in xml rather I wanted to insert these views pragmatically.

I'm able to add the view by saying  gridLayout.addView(view); but I'm unable to set the rowspan and columnSpan pragmatically.

Comment: Please post your code and try to be more clear and specific. I cannot understand the question.

Comment: i have added details as per your comment.

Comment: Have a look at the `GridLayout.LayoutParams` class.